# Scheme Trying to check if a word in the list

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp

I have a few functions.

```
 (define adjs '(black brown fast hairy hot quick red slow))
    (define adj?
        (lambda (a) (if (member a adjs) #t #f)
    )


    (define OK
        (lambda (x)
            (cond 
                ((equal? x()) #t)
                ((equal? adj? (car x)) OK(cdr x))
                ((else x            #f))
            )
       )
)
```

The function adj? is checking to see if the input is part of the list of adjectives in adjs.

What I am trying to do with the OK function is the user will input a list and have that list run through adj? to see if it is part of the adjs list.

What happens when I run the function is I get an error return that says I entered in "X" amount of arguments when the function only expected two. Why?

Comment: Your indentation makes it look like the definition of adj? is nested within adjs, but it's not.

Comment: And please don't throw your parentheses around like nail clippings.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to Scheme and I still have a lot of practicing to do. I promise, I will get better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are problems with the parentheses. Some are unnecessary and others are missing, for example when you recursively call the `OK` procedure, or in the way you're calling `adj?` - remember, in Scheme we call a procedure like this: `(f x)`, not like this: `f(x)`. Also, the base case of the recursion seems off, and the `else` clause is used incorrectly. Try this:

```
(define adj?
  (lambda (a)
    (if (member a adjs) #t #f)))

(define OK
  (lambda (x)
    (cond 
      ((null? x) #t)
      ((adj? (car x)) (OK (cdr x)))
      (else #f))))
```

Comment: I apologize for being so late to respond. I had an emergency to take care of. Ok, I understand what you're saying. In fact what you are suggesting makes perfect sense. Scheme is new for me and I am getting a lot of details confused. I just need to really practice the basics more.